# Objective-C class object not mapping to array

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsarray, amazon-dynamodb, object-object-mapping

How can I pass the event to the toDoArray? I'm not sure what I'm missing. Any help appreciated.

**SDEventModel.h**

```
@interface SDEventModel : AWSDynamoDBObjectModel <AWSDynamoDBModeling>
```

**ViewController.h**

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *toDoArray;
```

ViewController.m

```
    if (task.result) {
     AWSDynamoDBPaginatedOutput *paginatedOutput = task.result;
     for (SDEventModel *event in paginatedOutput.items) {
         //Do something with event.
         NSLog(@"Task results: %@", event);

         [self.toDoArray arrayByAddingObject:event];
         NSLog(@"To do array results: %@", self.toDoArray);

         [self.tableview reloadData];
     }
 }
```

**Here is the output of the NSLog.**

```
Task results: <SDEventModel: 0x7faa88d81430> {
city = "New York";
image = "photo-22.jpg";
title = "Hang with friends";
}
To do array results: (null)
```

Comment: I believe you didn't properly initialize the _toDoArray. You just started adding items to it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`arrayByAddingObject`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsarray/1408534-arraybyaddingobject) method returns another array with the added object, and does not append the same.

This is how the method is intended to be used:

```
self.toDoArray = [self.toDoArray arrayByAddingObject:event];
```

However, in your case, it seems that the array is not even initialized. So you need to do something like this as well:

```
-(void) viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.toDoArray = @[];
}
```

Comment: Thank you I see the array populated now.

Answer (score 1):

Define toDoArray as `NSMutableArray` like this in `ViewController.h`

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *toDoArray;
```

Now in `ViewController.m` initialise that array and add objects of event into it

```
if (task.result) {
     self.toDoArray = [NSMutableArray new];
     AWSDynamoDBPaginatedOutput *paginatedOutput = task.result;
     for (SDEventModel *event in paginatedOutput.items) {
         //Do something with event.
         NSLog(@"Task results: %@", event);
         [self.toDoArray addObject:event];
     }
         NSLog(@"To do array results: %@", self.toDoArray);
         [self.tableview reloadData];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check Whether the Array in which you are adding object is Mutable or not?
if it is not mutable, you can create a new array or convert existing array to Mutable Array using mutableCopy